# What are the possible pitfalls of reusing template ref values in Vue 3?

Tags: javascript, vue.js, vuejs3, vue-reactivity

Are there any issues with duplicating template ref values, ie `ref="foo"`, on the same type, but different instances, of a component across views in a Vue 3 app? Consider the example pseudocode below:

```html
// ROUTE A
<template>
  <MyTableComponent ref="foo" class="stylesForTable_ViewA"/>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  const foo = ref();
</script>

// ROUTE B (Never mounted at the same time as View A)
<template>
  <MyTableComponent ref="foo" class="stylesForTable_ViewB"/>
</template>

<script setup>
  import { ref } from "vue";
  const foo = ref();
</script>
```

In navigating from View A to View B, will Vue's reactivity system notice the same component type with the same `ref` value and attempt to construct View B by reusing the component instance in View A?

Comment: You're not reusing anything. They are totally refs in different comps, but it would be the same if it were the same comp.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

> In navigating from View A to View B, will Vue's reactivity system notice the same component type with the same ref value and attempt to construct View B by reusing the component instance in View A?

No, template refs are not shared between instances of the same component or across component boundaries. A new template ref (i.e., `foo` in this case) is created for each component instance: one for view A, and another for view B.